# Angular when server main page api is down redirect to another page

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I am using Angular CLI.
I am trying to write a code so:
the when Server for the main page api it is down - it will redirect the user to another page that i created.

Right now the server's main page doesn't work properly, and I want to redirect the client to another page 404- while i fix the bug on the main page.

Thank you for your suggestions !
:)

```
enter code here

export const environment = {
production: false, 
basePath: 'demo.aplication.eu/api', 
apiBasePath: 'demo.aplication.eu/repes/api', 
cpiBasePath: 'demo.aplication.eu/cpi', 
elisBasePath: 'ci.asano.ro/elisApi', 
docmanBasePath: 'demo.aplication.eu/docmanApi', 
googleMapsApiKey: 'AIzaSiDIV0uiLUobLB_JG1m4LVbccyQbu8DbfT0', 
domain: 'demo.aplication.eu', 
keycloakConfig: { url: 'demo.aplication.eu/auth', 
realm: 'ccdm', 
clientId: 'ccdm-authz-client' } 
};
```

Comment: Show some code..

Comment: If I understand correctly you meant you want to redirect to other page if an API call fails. Then, inject the router into the component/service and navigate to your desired page in case of a failure (check both error case and status codes)

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what i wanted to say. But i downt know how. Something with the ngIf

Comment: export const environment = {
  production: false,
  basePath: 'https://demo.aplication.eu/api',
  apiBasePath: 'https://demo.aplication.eu/repes/api',
  cpiBasePath: 'https://demo.aplication.eu/cpi',
  elisBasePath: 'https://ci.asano.ro/elisApi',
  docmanBasePath: 'https://demo.aplication.eu/docmanApi',
  googleMapsApiKey: 'AIzaSiDIV0uiLUobLB_JG1m4LVbccyQbu8DbfT0',
  domain: 'https://demo.aplication.eu',
  keycloakConfig: {
    url: 'https://demo.aplication.eu/auth',
    realm: 'ccdm',
    clientId: 'ccdm-authz-client'
  }
};

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A rough solution would be:

1. Create an ApiHealthService that keeps track of the state of the backend API using BehaviorSubject.
2. Create an endpoint on your API that responds up or down. For example /api/v1/foo/health
3. Export a function that calls the /api/v1/foo/health endpoint and store health status in your ApiHealthService.
4. Call function on application startup using a provider using APP_INITIALIZER in your app.module.ts
5. Using resolver or template logic in the component template, subscribe to BehaviorSubject.

See code on my github.com/ecruz165/edwincruz-com for an example of calling the application initializer.